# jaava NullPointerException

Tags: java

```
        class Process 
        {
          int PID;
        }

        Process[] processes = new Process[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter PID for process " + (i+1) );
            >>>processes[i].PID = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }
```

I got the exception in ">>>" What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's `br`?  How do you initialise it?

Comment: Process[] processes = new Process[n];

Look at the code, you just created an array of processes and you never put anything in that array.

Comment: You are creating an Array of processes, with 10 references to an actual `Procees`, which need to be initzialized first.

Comment: @KevinEsche can you tell me how to initialize? :)

Comment: @KevinEsche i tried processes[0].PID = 0; but the exception switch to that line when run

Comment: @kiddie write `processes[i] = new Process()` before you try to assign `PID`